# Are there any reasons why POW would ignore your .rvmrc file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rack-pow

My app of POW is the recent copy, I've installed and reinstalled it several times.

It will not register my .rvmrc file. It still loads the latest ( not the default ) ruby.

I've done the following.

1. Completely removed the app
   2 Completely uninstall pow
2. Completely uninstall powder
3. Removed ~/.pow
   5 Killed all instances of pow

Reinstalled everything. Still it will not read `.rvmrc`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that doesn't work for you, add the following line to your .rvmrc:

```
rvm env -- [your_ruby]@[your_gemset] >> .powenv
```

as detailed in the pow issue thread referenced above. Then restart Pow. That should do it.

Answer (score 4):

This is known issue: https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/271

the easiest solution(in project dir):

```
rvm env . > .powenv
```